# Can't get upload code to Arduino UNO from Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: arduino

Just finished installing arduino for the first time. I got a prompt about adding a user to a certain group. I accepted and continued. I tried to get the 'Blink' program to work. But everytime I try to upload, I get the following error;

> avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/ttyACM0": Input/output
>   error ioctl("TIOCMGET"): Invalid argument

I started arduino as root. I know this isn't suggested. But it was the only way I could get the "SERIAL PORT" to be ungreyed. After trying to upload code and getting that error. The serial port option becomes greyed out again.

- Did I install arduino incorrectly?
- How can I correct the mentioned error?
- What can I do to keep the serial port from being greyed out?

Comment: What is the output to the following commands: `ls -l /dev/ttyACM0` and `id`?

Comment: Also add the output to `dmesg | grep -iC5 ttyACM`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simple fix worked for me

sudo ln /dev/ttyACM0 /dev/ttySACM0

Apparently Ubuntu wants ttyS* for the usb port; it's a bit flakey about it so the ttyACM shows up then it disappears.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem wasn't solved with this command:

$ sudo ln /dev/ttyACM0 /dev/ttySACM0

maybe the usb port you are using is USB 3.0, then try plugging in a USB 2.0